# Create multidimensional array for duplicate ID key value

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read in array values from a csv and create sub-arrays which belong to the primary key field ID. E.g currently, say I have the following array structure & content...

ID;number;product

1;K12;product1

2;157/03/2014;product1

2;;product2

2;product1

3;156/03/2014;product2

3;156/03/2014;product3

I have a php function:

```
function csv_to_array($file, $delimiter=';')
{
    if(!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Such a result would like to achieve

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [LP] => 1
        [number] => K12
        [product] => product1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        Array
            (
                [LP] => 2
                [number] => 157/03/2014
                [product] => product1
            )
        Array
            (
                [product] => product2
            )               
        Array
            (
                [product] => product3
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
```

With

```
if(isset($data[$row[0]])) {
$data[$row[0]][] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
else {
$data[$row[0]] = array();
$data[$row[0]][] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```

Comment: it works ok, but as it read in the loop?
`function create($a){

 foreach ($a as $date) {

 }
 
 return $output;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
//$data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
if(isset($data[$row[0]])) {
    array_push($data[$row[0]], array('product' => $row[2]));
} else {
    $data[$row[0]] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{' in test.php on line 17:
if(isset($data[$row[0]]) {

Comment: @damian: yeah, missing `)`